# Error: variable-sized object may not be initialized?

Tags: gcc, x86, keyboard-events, inline-assembly, osdev

I am making a keyboard driver for my OSDev OS and i have a problem in my kbd.c:

```
kbd.c: In function 'scancoderec':
kbd.c:56:2: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
register int (ScanCode[strlen(ValEAX)-8]) = 0x00; /* Remove last 8 bits from the value we gathered from EAX to get AH and make that the scancode. */
```

Here is the function that contains the failing line of code:

```
int scancoderec() {
  __asm__ volatile( "movl $0, %eax" ); /* Moving 00 to EAX. */
  __asm__ volatile( "int $0x16 "); /*int 0x16 */
  register int ValEAX asm("eax"); /* Let's get eax */
  register int (ScanCode[strlen(ValEAX)-8]) = 0x00; /* Remove last 8 bits from the value we gathered from EAX to get AH and make that the scancode. */
}
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT: I still have that "ax" is undefined, this time, in another function.**

```
kbd.c:65:27: error: 'ax' undeclared (first use in this function)
register int Key = kbdus[ax];
```

Code of scancode function and getkey function:

```
    unsigned short scancodeget()
    {
       unsigned char ax = 0;    /* int 0x16, AH=0 is get keystroke */
       __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x16\n\t"
                             : "+a"(ax)); 
       ax = ax >> 8;       /* Shift top 8 bits of ax to lower 8 bits */
                       /* ax now is the scancode returned by BIOS */
       return (unsigned short)ax; /* Return the lower 8 bits */
}

int getkey() { /*This could be used as a keyboard driver. */
       scancoderec(); /*Get our scancode! */
       int Key = kbdus[ax]; /*Use our kbdus array which i copied from a website since i seriously don't want to make an gigantic array */
}
```

Comment: The compiler thinks you are declaring an array called `ScanCode`. Frankly, I have no idea what you're trying to do in that code.

Comment: Comment says "Remove last 8 bits from the value..."  --> looks like "Remove last 8 _bytes_ ..."

Comment: Hmmm, if `strlen(ValEAX) <= 8`, code will certainly have trouble.

Comment: `ax` (in my answer) was the name of a local variable defined inside `scancodeget()` so is only available inside that function. You can do something like `uint8_t scancode = scancodeget();` and then `int Key = kbdus[scancode];` . I gather you are new to the _C_ language?

Comment: And you have the types mixed up. It should be `unsigned short ax = 0;` (a 16-bit variable)  . The scancode being returned is only an 8-bit value so you can change `unsigned short scancodeget()` to `unsigned char scancodeget()` and `return (unsigned short)ax;` to `return (unsigned char)ax;`

Comment: If you look at my answer, `uint8_t` is `unsigned char` and `uint16_t` is `unsigned short`

Comment: Is this kernel (and the keyboard driver) running in protected mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very hard to tell what you were trying to achieve. This routine returns the raw scancode returned from [BIOS interrupt 16h/AH=0h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm). It uses [GCC extended assembler template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) using an [input/output constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints) to pass *AX* with value 0 into the assembler template and to retrieve the value in *AX* afterwards. The scancode is in the upper 8 bits of the `ax` variable so we shift it right by 8 bits.

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t getchar_scancode()
{
   uint16_t ax = 0;    /* int 0x16, AH=0 is get keystroke */
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x16\n\t"
                         : "+a"(ax)); 
                       /* +a is an input and output constraint using EAX register */
                       /* The contents of the 'ax' variable will be transferred */
                       /* into EAX register upon entry, and the value of EAX register */
                       /* will be transferred into variable 'ax' when finished */ 
   ax = ax >> 8;       /* Shift top 8 bits of ax to lower 8 bits */
                       /* ax now is the scancode returned by BIOS */
   return (uint8_t)ax; /* Return the lower 8 bits */
}
```

If you don't have `stdint.h`available to define `uint16_t` you can replace it with `unsigned short` and replace `uint8_t` with `unsigned char`.

If you need to convert a scancode to an ASCII character you can use additional functions to provide that functionality:

```
unsigned char kbdus[128] =
{
    0,  27, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',   /* 9 */
    '9', '0', '-', '=', '\b',                         /* Backspace */
    '\t',                                             /* Tab */
    'q', 'w', 'e', 'r',                               /* 19 */
    't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n',     /* Enter key */
    0,                                                /* 29   - Control */
    'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', /* 39 */
    '\'', '`',   0,                                   /* Left shift */
    '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n',               /* 49 */
    'm', ',', '.', '/',   0,                          /* Right shift */
    '*',
    0,                                                /* Alt */
    ' ',                                              /* Space bar */
    0,                                                /* Caps lock */
    0,                                                /* 59 - F1 key ... > */
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,                                                /* < ... F10 */
    0,                                                /* 69 - Num lock*/
    0,                                                /* Scroll Lock */
    0,                                                /* Home key */
    0,                                                /* Up Arrow */
    0,                                                /* Page Up */
    '-',
    0,                                                /* Left Arrow */
    0,
    0,                                                /* Right Arrow */
    '+',
    0,                                                /* 79 - End key*/
    0,                                                /* Down Arrow */
    0,                                                /* Page Down */
    0,                                                /* Insert Key */
    0,                                                /* Delete Key */
    0,   0,   0,
    0,                                                /* F11 Key */
    0,                                                /* F12 Key */
    0, /* All other keys are undefined */
};

uint8_t getchar()
{
    return (kbdus[getchar_scancode()]);
}
```

---

BIOS Interrupts will not work in protected mode and will likely fault the machine. *INT 16h/AH=0* only works in real mode.

Comment: I do have uint16_t/uint8_t. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: But how do i make a key out of it using something like `int Key = kbdus[ax]`? It gives me that ax is not defined, even though in the same function it calls the getchar_scancode();.

Comment: `ax` is a variable name like any other. You should be able to do something like `int Key = kbdus[getchar_scancode()]` or do `uint8_t scancode = getchar_scancode(); int Key = kbdus[scancode];`

Comment: And when I mean `ax` is just like any variable, `ax` was defined as a local variable in `getchar_scancode`, so is only visible inside that function. The cancode is returned from that function.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough. You may not initialize a variable length array. Write instead

```
register int (ScanCode[strlen(ValEAX)-8]);
ScanCode[0] = 0x00;
```

Or you can use standard C function `memset`, declared in header `<string.h>` to set all elements of the vector to `0x00`.

For example

```
memset( ScanCode, 0x00, sizeof( ScanCode ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
register int (ScanCode[strlen(ValEAX)-8]) = 0x00;
```

declares a VLA and tries to initialize it, which is not allowed. Change that to:

```
// Declare
int size = strlen(ValEAX)-8
register int ScanCode[size];

// Set values.
for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
   ScanCode[i] = 0x00;
}
```